# How to split PlatformUI.getWorkbench().restart() step?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to do some actions between close and start of application.

So I am writing PlatformUI.getWorkbench().close() to close the application and i am executing the actions which i required. Now i don't know how to start the workbench back again.

**Code snippet:**

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().close(); <- closing application

//Executing set of task ; <- trying to uninstall some plugins and features. While uninstalling application should not be opened so added above step.

PlatformUI.getWorkbench().restart(); <- again trying to open application but facing swt null pointer exception
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do stuff before shutdown, use:

```
org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.preShutdown()
org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.postShutdown()
```

In your main RCP plugin there should be a class extending `org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor`.

```
public class MyApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor extends WorkbenchAdvisor {

    @Override
    public boolean preShutdown() {
        // ... YOUR CODE
    }
}
```

If you want to restart the workbench manually you can use:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().restart()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need to do some task that works only after shutdown(using PlatformUI.getWorkbench().close()). Then i am executing my tasks. After that i need to open the same workbench(should get same perspective and views before the shutdown what we had). Is it possible to open the same workbench???

Comment: And to start the application if i use the restart method then i am getting swt null pointer exception.

Comment: `restart()` should bring back the previous perspectives and views. At what point do you call `restart()`, if the workbench is already shutting down `PlatformUI.getWorkbench()` might be null.

Comment: Yes. Is it possible to close() and reopen workbench explicitly??

Comment: Could you post some code? Where and how do you close the application? `restart()` should close and reopen the workbench.

Comment: Please find the code snippet in the above description